# Изменение положения углока resize

Tags: html, css, resize

Есть блок со свойством `resize: both`.

[image: Пример блока]

Так вот, как изменить положение этого уголка (нужно вверху справа)?

Гуглил, нашёл только информацию о том, что его положение можно изменить на снизу слева, свойством `direction: rtl;`.

Comment: А можете уточнить, что за тип блока? Это textarea, и если, да, то должен ли оставаться функционал resize ? Дело в том, что если это не принципиально, то задача очень упрощается =)

Comment: Это `<div>` и функционал resize должен остаться.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать jQuery UI:

```js
$( "#resizable" ).resizable();
```

```css
@import url(https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css);

.ui-widget-content {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #333 !important;
  color:#fff !important;
}
.ui-icon, 
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
  top: .5rem;
  
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px !important;
  
  background-image: url(https://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../assets/preview/2012/png/iconmonstr-resize-11.png&r=255&g=255&b=255) !important;
  
  background-position: 0px 0px !important;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h2>Resize Content</h2>
  
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, error.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Когда-то делал похожую штуку, может пригодится.

```js
   var prevDrag = document.getElementById("prev-drag");
var grab = document.getElementById("grab");

if ( grab != undefined ) {
grab.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var Xc = evt.pageX;
    var Yc = evt.pageY;
    var oW = prevDrag.offsetWidth;
    var oH = prevDrag.offsetHeight;
    var self = evt;
    document.body.onmousemove = function (event) { 
        prevDrag.style.width = ( oW + ( event.pageX - Xc)) + "px";
        prevDrag.style.height = (oH - ( event.pageY - Yc)) + "px";
    }
    document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
         document.body.onmousemove = function () {};
    })
})
}
```

```css
.prew-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;;
} 

.prev-drag {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    transition: .1s all;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#grab {
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #fffffff0;
    background-color: #ff3030;
    background-origin: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="prew-container">
  <div class="prev-drag" id="prev-drag" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
   <div id="grab"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно отразить по вертикали два раза

```css
#wrap {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    transform: scale(1, -1);
}

#content {
    transform: scale(1, -1);
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
        123
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Тогда это всё упрощает. Можно так.

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: background;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

С textarea там шрифт как-то крутить надо. Наверное можно как-то и красивше, но там уже JS тянуть надо

Comment: Пожалуй придётся использовать js

Comment: Этот код неверно работает